# Windows alternative of this python script for linux to get IP from URL

Tags: python, linux

I am very new to Python. So in newboston's latest python tutorial Im making a web crawler. This Python script however only works on Linux. What would be the windows alternative to the following code?

```
import os

def get_ip_address(url):
  command = "host " + url     
  process = os.popen(command)
  results = str(process.read())
  marker = results.find('has address') + 12
  return results[marker:].splitlines()[0]

print(get_ip_address('google.com'))
```

I want it in the same format as I want to code multiple modules(i.e. get ip, who is etc.) and put them together as one Python program.

I am trying to obtain ONLY the ip address and nothing else in the results.

Alternatively, This is what I have for Windows so far:

```
import socket

def get_ips_for_host(url):
    try:
        ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(url)
    except socket.gaierror:
        ips = []
    return ips

ips = get_ips_for_host('www.facebook.com')
print(repr(ips))
```

How can i modify it to make it get only the IP address?

> Similarly how can I get the nmap scan and the 'who is'?

Answer (score 1):

```
the_ip = get_ips_for_host('www.facebook.com')[-1][0]
```